# Glue custom classifiers for CSV with non standard delimiter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to use AWS Glue to crawl a data set and make it available to query in Athena. My data set is a delimited text file using ^ to separate columns. Glue is not able to infer the schema for this data as the CSV classifier only recognises comma (,), pipe (|), tab (\t), semicolon (;), and Ctrl-A (\u0001). Is there a way of updating this classifer to include non standard delimeters? The option to build custom classifiers only seems to support Grok, JSON or XML which are not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a custom classifier using the custom Grok pattern and use that in the crawler. Suppose your data is like below with four fields:

```
qwe^123^22.3^2019-09-02
```

To process the above data, your custom pattern will look like below:

```
%{NOTSPACE:name}^%{INT:class_num}^%{BASE10NUM:balance}^%{CUSTOMDATE:balance_date}
```

Please let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Does this mean we have to know the structure of file beforehand and if yes, doesn't it defeat the purpose of Glue crawler? Also, why can't we use a csv classifier here and give ^ as the delimiter ?

Comment: Glue crawler comes with predefined set of classifiers. You will need to go to the custom classifier path only when you find that the glue pre-built classifieres are not detecting your data properly. And yes, the custom classifier shown in the answer is itself is a custom csv classifier which will detect both columns and data types.

Comment: My scenario is very similar to OP. What i meant to ask you is : 1) when u said "suppose your data is like below with four fields", in this case, i assume we have to know the number of columns and their datatypes and then only we can create this custom classifier. If there is other way to create this without knowing the content of the file, please let me know. 2) i could see an option of custom classifier for csv as well where a delimiter can be given in the 'other' option but its not working for me.